# Mount SSHFS to tmpfs/Memory/MiniDLNA just write to RAM

Tags: debian, raspberry-pi, services, daemon, tmpfs

to reduce the I/O on my low end Raspberry Pi,
I want to set my SSHFS/NFS to be mounted in RAM.

MiniDLNA then will stream it to my Network.
As I can see in IOtop, Minidlna uses 99% of IO usage, and I think it is from the SSHFS/NFS mount.

How can I get Minidlna to work only from RAM?
I couldn't find a 'real' Cache/Working Directory for Minidlna/Samba, only for indexed Files(DB) and so.

Easy to say, all the File get/stream should go in Memory and not on the internal drive (SD Card).

As all File Operations are at the remote Share, it should be possible?
Just like a Live Stream..

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a comment earlier about the following approach:

```
sudo mount -t tmpfs -o size=1g tmpfs /mnt/tmpfs
sudo mkdir /mnt/tmpfs/sshfs
sudo sshfs rowan@10.0.5.5:/home/rowan/sshfs /mnt/tmpfs/sshfs/.
```

This where my results:

```
tmpfs                             1.0G     0  1.0G   0% /mnt/tmpfs
rowan@10.0.5.5:/home/rowan/sshfs  683G  7.2G  641G   2% /mnt/tmpfs/sshfs
```

This won't work, since sshfs is making a new mountpoint itself. So the previous mountpoint doesn't even matter.

I think (could be wrong), that sshfs already buffers writes in RAM before it sends it over. Sorry I couldn't be more helpful.

Comment: Okay, yes thats also my thought that SSHFS already uses RAM.
Then minidlna Service, which reads from the share must be my problem.

I will edit the Question, need to solve to run services like SSHFS, to work only in RAM.

Comment: New Question:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/493768/samba-minidlna-use-ram-as-working-cache-directory