# SAMBA/MiniDLNA: Use RAM as working/Cache Directory?

Tags: debian, raspberry-pi, samba, services, daemon

As a follow-up to [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/493751/mount-sshfs-to-tmpfs-memory-minidlna-just-write-to-ram):

I want to reduce High I/O Load on Raspberry Pi when streaming with MiniDLNA from an SSHFS/NFS Share.

At 'iotop' I could see MiniDLNA/Samba uses over 99% Disk I/O Traffic Usage.
The SSHFS Service is low at I/O usage.

Now I couldn't find an option to run MiniDLNA/Samba only in RAM, or just to change working/real Cache Directory. (Could be changed to tmpfs)

-Is it possible to run MiniDLNA/SAMBA 'only' in RAM to reduce Disk I/O Load?

Should be possible,or? SSHFS is already using RAM as 'Read Buffer' or whatever the correct terminus is ;)
Shouldn't this be easy, all Data will get transfered 'on-the-fly'/instant from SSHFS Share to DLNA/SAMBA Client...

Comment: Is the disk that MiniDLNA/Samba use on a usb device and are you using ethernet?

Comment: The disk is mounted over Ethernet

Comment: I think [this thread is related](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2334115) to your issue. Please [edit your post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/493768/edit) to include the output of `iotop -o`